# HTML начать воспроизведение аудиозаписи, не дождавшись полной буферизации

Tags: html, аудио, web-audio

Есть HTML-код:

```
<audio src="http://myserver/audio.wav" autoload />
```

Длительность аудиозаписи около 7 часов. Файл грузится слишком долго. Есть ли возможность воспроизводить аудио сразу, как только началась загрузка, то есть, например, если за несколько секунд была получена лишь некоторая часть аудиозаписи, то как воспроизвести её сразу, не дожидавшись окончания получения целого файла? Файл не обязательно должен быть в аудио формате WAV.

Comment: `autoplay` пробовали?

Comment: @webDev_, да;;;